# MS Excel VBA- hiding rows based on a cell value doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

I am very much a novice and am trying to get certain rows to show/hide based on values in certain cells when a command button is pressed.  I need help with 2 things:

1) Would like this to actually work without pressing a button. I.e. each time the value of cell C10 is changed the code runs to hide/show.

2) I have 4 subroutines that run when the button is pressed.  Three of them work fine. I can't get "Rows1to13" subroutine to run.  Can't understand it because t's te same exact routine I'm just changing the cells that trigger it and changing which range of rows get hidden.

My code is below

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Call HideDefault
    Call rows1to13
End Sub

Sub HideDefault()

    If (Range("C10")) = "Manual" Then
        For a = 44 To 90
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(a, 1).Value >= "0" Then
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(a).Hidden = True
            End If
        Next
        For a = 92 To 125
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(a, 1).Value >= "0" Then
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(a).Hidden = False
            End If
        Next
    End If

    If (Range("C10")) = "Manual" Then
        MsgBox "Manual Data Entry chosen"
    End If

End Sub

Sub rows1to13()
    'and if C11=yes and C16=yes'

    If (Range("C11")) = "Yes" Then
        For a = 12 To 13
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(a, 1).Value >= "0" Then
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(a).Hidden = False
            End If
        Next
    End If

    If (Range("C16")) = "Yes" Then
        For a = 17 To 20
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(a, 1).Value >= "0" Then
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(a).Hidden = False
            End If
        Next
    End If

    'and if C11=No and C16=No'

    If (Range("C11")) = "No" Then
        For a = 12 To 13
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(a, 1).Value >= "0" Then
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(a).Hidden = True
            End If
        Next
    End If

    If (Range("C16")) = "No" Then
        For a = 12 To 13
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(a, 1).Value >= "0" Then
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(a).Hidden = True
            End If
        Next
    End If

    'and if C11= blank and C16= Blank'

    If (Range("C11")) = "" Then
        For a = 12 To 13
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(a, 1).Value >= "0" Then
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(a).Hidden = False
            End If
        Next
    End If

    If (Range("C16")) = "" Then
        For a = 17 To 20
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(a, 1).Value >= "0" Then
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(a).Hidden = False
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How is the value in C10 changed? Manually or by formula?

Comment: The value in C10 is changed manually. It is also changed by hitting a button wihch resets the sheet to remove all entered data.  C11 and C16 are the same.  The code with C10 works, its the C11 and C16 ones that do not

Comment: My question was in view of automation. So you should use the Change Event. And how are C11 and C16 changed? Describe a little more the problems with C11 and C16.

Comment: When I press the commandbutton, Subroutine HideDefault works fine.  It shows/hides rows if C10 value = "Tpx Default".  I basically copy/pasted the code for that functioning code several times and changed from C10 to C11 or C16 along with changing the rows that get shown/hidden to cover the scenarios I need.  When I press the button rows 12-13 (C11) and rows 17-20 (C16) should show/hide based on if C11/C16 are Yes No or Blank.  NOthing happens at all.

Comment: @JoeR - Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53965460/edit) instead of adding information in comments? It will make things a lot clearer for everyone

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue why the code wasn't executing.  .  It was very simple. The code is looking for value in a cell to execute, and it case sensitive.  In the worksheet the cell input was done in Caps i.e. "NO", but the code was written to look for "No".

Used the worksheet change event to execute without having to press button.  Thanks VBasic2008